# PL/SQL Developer: disconnect, yet allow the query to continue

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Using PL/SQL Developer by AllRound Automations, is there a way, during a long-running query, to disconnect yet allow the query to continue to completion, when running on an Oracle database?

Comment: I don't think so.  Schedule a job with oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Comment: It is impossible. You can try to kill process of PLSQL Developer using windows task manager. Sometimes session stays active, but nobody guarantees the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dmitry says:

> It is impossible. You can try to kill process of PLSQL Developer using
>   windows task manager. Sometimes session stays active, but nobody
>   guarantees the result